# Force 'Implement members' option in ReSharper to use explicit interface implementations

Tags: c#, resharper

I can't find this in ReSharper options! Can anyone point me to where it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as you have added an interface to the class, you can bring up the Implement Members dialog. In ReSharper 8.2 I have a drop down box at the bottom labeled "Implement as" which I can set to "Explicit Implementation"

[image: Implement Members Dialog]

Comment: Nice! Cheers dude. Do you know if there's any way to make that be the default option every time??

Comment: I do not know about such a possibility which does not mean it is not there somewhere. Indeed I would not recommend to implement all interface member explicitly unless there is a good reason to do so.